# How to sort an array in this way in php

Tags: php, sorting

like the function usort in php
but if two members compare as equal, their key should be same.
for example:
$arrayToSort = array(2,6,1,3,3);

after sort return

```
array
  1 =>  1
  2 =>  2
  3 =>  3
  3 =>  3
  4 =>  6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a native function but this *might* be what you want.

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,2,2,3);

function arrayKeyJoin( $arr ) {
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ( $arr as $item ) {
 if ( !in_array( $item, array_keys($newArr) ) ) {
     $newArr[$item] = array();
 }
 array_push( $newArr[$item], $item );
    }
    return $newArr;
}

echo '<pre>', var_dump( arrayKeyJoin( $arr ) ), '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In response to meder's answer, you're using slow functions such as `in_array()` and `array_push()` instead of fast constructs such as `isset()` or the `[]` operator. Your code should look like this:

```
$arr = array(1,2,2,2,3);

$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $v)
{
    $new[$v][] = $v;
}

// then you can sort the array if you wish
ksort($new);
```

Note that what you're doing is similar, in some way, to PHP's own [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two elements with the same key in an array. You can, however, group the two threes into one array, so that 1=> 1, 2 => 2, and 3 => array(3,3).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two keys that are the same.  Keys are unique.

If you try to create it in code, here's what happens.

```
$data[1] = 1;  // Assigns value 1 to key 1;   1 element in array
$data[2] = 2;  // Assigns value 2 to key 2;   2 elements in array
$data[3] = 3;  // Assigns value 3 to key 3;   3 elements in array
$data[3] = 3;  // Reassigns value 3 to key 3; STILL 3 elements in array
$data[4] = 6;  // Assigns value 6 to key 4;   4 elements in array
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't make sense. You can't have two equal keys in the same array. If you want to sort the array's values and have their keys preserved, use [`asort()`](http://php.net/asort). Or any of the functions in the table at http://ca.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php that say "yes" under "Maintains key association".